# HTML: Lists, Sublist and Pseudo Elements

Tags: html, list, css

I need to create a list similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/BkBZJ/

Only, without the extra markup in the HTML (span tags with classes or nested lists within lists).
Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this, say with a pseudo element such as before/after, last-child, nth-child etc...

or is this not possible without the additional markup in the HTML.

Comment: `::before` and `::after` are pseudo-elements, whereas `:last-child` and `:nth-child()` are pseudo-classes. They are two different things; don't mix them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could always use :nth-child(x) where x is the one you want to modify, and then apply a margin-left to it as well as a color: change to it.

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/PcA4u/

Comment: this wont work for what I am after noah, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I misunderstood how to use this suggestion properly...using this answer provided and altering it a tad to be more minimal for the HTML, I can achieve this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JZF5v/

thank you Noah

Answer (score 1):

Simply do [the following (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/BkBZJ/1/):

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #202024; 
    color: #FFF;
    font: .75em Arial, san-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 1.25em Arial, san-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#education dt { margin-top: 15px;}
#education dd {
    text-indent: 25px;
    color:#C5B7A6;
}
/* Add the dashes where appropriate */
#education dd:before {
    content: "- ";
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Override the styles for specific dds */
#education .co {color:#FFF; margin-left:50px;}

/* Or, alternately if all except the first dd should be white */
#education dd:first-child { color: #C5B7A6; margin-left: 0; }
#education dd { color: #FFF; margin-left: 50px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="education">
<h1>Education</h1>
<dl>
    <dt>Holmsglen Institute of TAFE</dt>
        <dd>Certificate II &amp; Certificate III of Multimedia</dd>
    <dt>RMIT University</dt>
        <dd>Advanced Diploma Of Interactive Media</dd>
    <dd>2D Animation Major</dd>
    <dt>Swinburne University</dt>
        <dd>Bachelors Degree of Digital Media</dd>
        <dd class="co">Branding &amp; Advertising Co-Minor</dd>
        <dd class="co">Motion Graphics Co-Minor</dd>
</dl> 
</div>​
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response sean, I was hoping to avoid adding more classes and looking for a pseudo way around this.  This might have to do as a last resort.

Comment: @Rob - see my edit for a way to do it without the classes on the later `dd` elements. (Just use `:first-child` to change the way the first `dd` is displayed).

Comment: the best I can get so far is http://jsfiddle.net/BkBZJ/5/.  im not sure exactly on how to target the second dd using your method of :first-child.